# Animation duration decreases apon time

Tags: android, animation

I am developing demonstator application. I have a FrameLayout. I need to show and hide different TextViews on it from time to time. And I am using this code to show view:

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(DetailsActivity.this,android.R.anim.fade_in);
a.setDuration(duration);

Log.d("animation duration", duration + " add");
mTextLayout.addView(text, lParams);
text.startAnimation(a);
```

Where `mTextLayout` is `FrameLayout`, and `text` is a `TextView` to show

The problem is that when the application runns for more than 10 minutes, the animation duration is reduced somehow, and finally after 30 min. it just ignores the animation and simply shows and hides the TextViews without any animations. Does anybody have any idea about whi does it happen and how to fix this probem?

Comment: @Martijn Van Mierloo, it's Asus Fonepad. I do not think that it is not good enough to do work like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38581) issue on Android Issue Tracker Android 4.1.2 has some problems with hardware acceleration and Animations. Asus Fonepad is running 4.1.2. Today I have tested on other device with later Android version(4.2.2), and everything worked ok.